# Pandas change date format in a file

Tags: python, pandas

```
df['dates'] =pd.to_datetime(df.dates, format='%d-%m-%Y')
df.sort_values(by='dates', ascending=False).to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

And I look 2017-09-20 in my file, but before run code, it was like 20-09-2017.
I want to use only %d-%m-%Y format.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`date_format`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) parameter:

```
df.to_csv('/path/to/file.csv', date_format='%d-%m-%Y')
```